# Setting attribute value to "none" for QWebElement

Tags: qt

I am trying to set a value "None" for a "display" attribute for the QWebElemnt `child` like this(also tried none and NONE):

`child.setStyleProperty("display",None)`

but i recieve only 1 error:'None isnt declared in this scope. I am not sure, that iam doing ANYTHING right, because i looked up in the internet for the styles for the webelement, and there was nothing. I am just told, that there should be that "display" attribute. So, how can i set it to "None"?
Thanks

Comment: Which language that is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're first supposed to think about what you're doing, not "looking up in the internet". Start with the basics: are you calling the right method with the right  arguments?

The signature of the method you're calling is (this is straight from the documentation):

```
void QWebElement::setStyleProperty(const QString & name, const QString & value)
```

Thus it expects a string as the second argument. You want, then:

```
child.setStyleProperty("display", "none");
```